# Android force close showing 'javax.net.ssl.SSLException' in device on app installation

Tags: android

I had developed an android app.It works fine in emulator. When i tried to install the same apk file in my device, App shows 'Unfortunately app has stopped' and terminates the installation.
I tried many times by reinstalling the app. Please help with a solution. Thanks in advance.
Output in logcat is given below:

```
    W/System.err( 4272): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1449be8: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:410)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:643)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:614)
    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.<init>(SocketInputBuffer.java:70)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:83)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(DefaultClientConnection.java:170)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.bind(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:106)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.openCompleted(DefaultClientConnection.java:129)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:172)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at com.getjar.sdk.comm.CommManager.processesRequest(CommManager.java:563)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at com.getjar.sdk.comm.CommManager.processesRequestWithRetries(CommManager.java:409)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at com.getjar.sdk.comm.CommManager.access$1200(CommManager.java:60)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at com.getjar.sdk.comm.CommManager$RequestCallable.call(CommManager.java:1124)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at com.getjar.sdk.comm.CommManager$RequestCallable.call(CommManager.java:1114)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)

    W/System.err( 4272):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885247/why-is-httpurlconnection-throwing-an-sslexception-while-on-a-mobile-data-connect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885247/why-is-httpurlconnection-throwing-an-sslexception-while-on-a-mobile-data-connect

Comment: But i have another similiar app which works fine with same configuration on wifi.Thanks

Comment: I also got the same exception. I found that it was due to TLS 1.0 protocol was not supported by server. I observed that Android device, http connection fails to the server where TLS 1.0 is not supported. I searched every where about the bug, but did not find anything related to this problem. And the problem was solved, when the TLS 1.0 protocol support was added to the server.You can check your server / hostname protocol support using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest.

Comment: @SwapnilKale Me to facing same issue i have Took SSL test from the url given by you and there TLS 1.0 is supported by server. So please tell me some other solution. App is working fine on emulator but not on device

Comment: @user2990478 Have you found any solution for this?