# Android Https URL issue

Tags: java, android, android-activity, https

I tried to connect https url using android but it wasn't works.It  shows below message

```
Java.net.SSL.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x76c88b60: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
```

This is my client code

```
public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new ExSSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: test your server for TSL 1.0 support  here https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885247/why-is-httpurlconnection-throwing-an-sslexception-while-on-a-mobile-data-connect

Comment: it support only TSL 1.2